# while citing a paper in place of pages I need to put article

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

This is what I am getting while referencing in IEEE format.....

> D. Sain, M. Praharaj, and M. M. Bosukonda, “A simple modelling
> strategy for integer order and fractional order interval type-2 fuzzy PID
> controllers with their simulation and real-time implementation,” Expert
> Systems with Applications, vol. 202, **p. 117196**, 2022.

but what I need is this...

> D. Sain, M. Praharaj, and M. M. Bosukonda, “A simple modelling
> strategy for integer order and fractional order interval type-2 fuzzy PID
> controllers with their simulation and real-time implementation,” Expert
> Systems with Applications, vol. 202, **Article. 117196**, 2022.

NOTE: The difference lies in page number and article.

My BibTeX file contains the following :

```
@article{sain2022simple,
    title = {A simple modelling strategy for integer order and fractional order interval type-2 fuzzy {PID} controllers with their simulation and real-time implementation},
    journal = {Expert Systems with Applications},
    volume = {202},
    pages = {117196},
    year = {2022},
    issn = {0957-4174},
    author = {Debdoot Sain and Manoranjan Praharaj and Murali Mohan Bosukonda},
    keywords = {IT2 fuzzy control, Mathematical modelling, IOIT2FPID, FOIT2FPID, Real-time implementation, Magnetic levitation},
}
```

my bibliography style is

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}.
```

I am just citing by using the command `\cite{sain2022simple}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short TeX code producing the shown reference? Do not forget to add the bib entry too!

Comment: Please [edit] your original post with the relevant information.  Don't put it in comments.

Comment: Can you also show the tex code you are using to get those references?  The bibliographic style is definitely relevant, and probably other items as well.

Comment: @Teepeemm I am using the code as \cite{sain2022simple}.

my bibliography style is 

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

Comment: Easy solutions: Either you write a new format for chapter = {x}, which you can access per article with options = {newchapterformat}, or you add the article number with the field library = {Article x}. I prefer the first, because the article number is very close to a chapter.

Comment: What happens if you write `chapter = 117196`?